# conditional CSS in dart polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to figure out how to get the visibility of two elements to toggle based on the same variable. Wrapping the elements with  isn't an option, since I need to interact with the elements while they're invisible. I tried this, which I found an example of somewhere, but it didn't work, both elements are always visible:

```dart
  #fieldsList {
    display:{{ {none: editing == true, block: editing == false} | tokenList }};
  }
  #fieldsEdit {
    display:{{ {none: editing == false, block: editing == true } | tokenList}};
  }
```

And I tried it by wrapping the CSS in template conditionals, but this also results in both elements being always visible:

```dart
  <template if="{{ editing == true}}">
    #fieldsList {
      display: none;
    }
  </template>
  <template if="{{ editing == false}}">
    #fieldsEdit {
      display: none;
    }
  </template>
```

Am I going about this wrong? I'm using Dart 1.7.2 with Polymer 0.15.1+5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional CSS like this:

```
#fieldsList {
  display:{{editing ? 'none' : 'block'}};
}
#fieldsEdit {
  display:{{editing ? 'block' : 'none'}};
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, some conditional syntax. Works great, thanks much!

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would use the `hidden` attribute, like so:

`<div id="fieldsList" hidden?="{{editing}}">`

and

`<div id="fieldsEdit" hidden?="{{!editing}}">`

Polymer includes CSS that looks for the presence of the `hidden` attribute and applies the appropriate CSS. The `?=` syntax removes and applies the attribute based on the boolean expression.

Comment: This works! Pixel Elephant's suggestion is more general purpose, and it answers the general question of conditional CSS, so I'm going to mark his answer as correct, but this is the implementation I'm going to use this time.

Answer (score 1):

According to the discussion in https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/270 the best supported way (cross-browser) is to use the `<core-style>` element https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-style